# Como mostrar mensagem no retorno de postagem de contato

Tags: php, javascript, css

Tenho um formulário de contato onde envio as informações inseridas para o meu `BD`, gostaria de deixar uma mensagem ao usuário após a submissão do form e não estou tendo sucesso, o que fiz foi isso:

Tenho uma `div` posicionada acima do meu `form`, assim:

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Ao submeter o `form` faço uma validação dos campos do mesmo e tendo emitir a mensagem, está assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   // Scripts de submissão
  $('.contactForm').submit( function(){
        //statements to validate the form   
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        var email = document.getElementById('e-mail');

        if (document.cform.nome.value == "") {
            $('.nome-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.nome-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });}   

        if (document.cform.telefone.value == "") {
            $('.telefone-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.telefone-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });}       

        if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
            $('.email-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.email-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });}

        if (document.cform.cidade.value == "") {
            $('.cidade-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.cidade-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });} 

        if (document.cform.uf.value == "") {
            $('.uf-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.uf-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });}         

        if (document.cform.assunto.value == "") {
            $('.assunto-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.assunto-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });}                    

        if (document.cform.mensagem.value == "") {
            $('.mensagem-missing').css({'opacity': 1 });
        } else {$('.mensagem-missing').css({'opacity': 0 });}   


        if ((document.cform.nome.value == "")       || 
            (document.cform.telefone.value == "")   || 
            (!filter.test(email.value))             || 
            (document.cform.cidade.value == "")     || 
            (document.cform.uf.value == "")         || 
            (document.cform.assunto.value == "")    || 
            (document.cform.mensagem.value == "")) {
            return false;
        } 

        if ((document.cform.nome.value != "")       && 
            (document.cform.telefone.value != "")   && 
            (!filter.test(email.value))             && 
            (document.cform.cidade.value != "")     && 
            (document.cform.uf.value != "")         && 
            (document.cform.assunto.value != "")    && 
            (document.cform.mensagem.value != "")) {

            // Mostrar a barra de carregamento
            $('.loader').append();

            //send the ajax request
            $.post('processo.php',{
                                nome:$('#nome').val(),
                                telefone:$('#telefone').val(),                              
                                email:$('#e-mail').val(),
                                cidade:$('#cidade').val(),
                                uf:$('#uf').val(),
                                assunto:$('#assunto').val(),
                                mensagem:$('#mensagem').val()
                                },

            // Retornar os dados
            function(data){
              // Oculta
              $('.loader').append(data).slideDown(800);
            });

            // Espera 2000, em seguida, fecha o formulário e desaparece
            setTimeout('$(".resposta").slideUp(800)', 6000);

            // Permanecer na página
            return false;
        } 
  }); 
});
```

O meu `.php` está assim:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$mensagem = nl2br($_POST['mensagem']);


$subject = $assunto;
$body = "From $nome, \n\n$mensagem";
$headers = 'From: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


mail("email@gmail.com", $subject, $body, $headers);
```

```
<div class="resposta">
<h4>Obrigado <?php echo $nome ?>!</h4>
<p>Em breve entraremos em contato com você.</p>
```

O `css` da `div` resposta está assim:

```
    .resposta {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Eu acredito que há maneiras melhores e mais simples de fazer esse envio utilizando o método  `$.ajax({ ... })`. Quanto a validação, é mais fácil e seguro fazer isso direto no PHP e retornar a mensagem via ajax. Vou tentar elaborar uma resposta, só que vai ficar longa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para começar pense em fazer a validação no PHP, chamando uma página via ajax, instanciando a classe conforme abaixo:

```
class SendEmail
{
   private $nome;
   private $email;
   private $telefone;
   private $cidade;
   private $assunto;
   private $mensagem;
   private $receive_mail;

   public function __construct($data)
   {

    $this->receive_mail = "email@gmail.com";
      try
      {
        if (count($data) < 6) {
           throw new Exception("Todos os dados devem ser preenchidos.");
        }

        if ($data['nome'] == "") {
           throw new Exception("Preencha seu nome completo corretamente.");
        }

        if ($data['email'] == "") {
             throw new Exception("Preencha seu e-mail corretamente.");
        }

        if (!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
             throw new Exception("Preencha um e-mail válido.");
        }

        if ($data['telefone'] == "") {
             throw new Exception("Preencha seu telefone corretamente.");
        }

        if (!preg_match('/\([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{4,5}/', $data['telefone'])) {
             throw new Exception("Preencha um número corretamente, exemplo: (11) 1234-1234.");
        }

        if ($data['cidade'] == "") {
             throw new Exception("Preencha a cidade corretamente.");
        }

        if ($data['assunto'] == "") {
             throw new Exception("Preencha o assunto corretamente.");
        }

        if ($data['mensagem'] == "") {
             throw new Exception("Preencha a mensagem corretamente.");
        }
        //envia a mensagem
         return $this->sendMail();

      } catch (Exception $e) {
            return json_encode(array('success'=>'0','errors'=>$e->getMessage()));
      }    

     }

     public function sendMail()
     {
      $subject = $this->assunto;
      $body = "From {$this->nome}, \n\n{nl2br($this->mensagem)}";
      $headers = 'From: ' . $this->email . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: ' . $this->email . "\r\n" .
        'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

       if (mail($this->receive_mail, $this->assunto, $body, $headers)) {
          return json_encode(array('success'=>'1','message'=>'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!'));
       } else {
          throw new Exception("Ocorreu um erro no envio da mensagem, por favor, tente mais tarde.");
       }
     }
}

if ($_POST) {
    //aqui ele retornará um JSON com os erros ou a mensagem de sucesso
    echo new SendEmail($_POST);
}
```

Agora no javaScript, execute o método em ajax:

```
function sedMail() {
   var data = {
       nome:$('#nome').val(),
       telefone:$('#telefone').val(),                              
       email:$('#e-mail').val(),
       cidade:$('#cidade').val(),
       uf:$('#uf').val(),
       assunto:$('#assunto').val(),
       mensagem:$('#mensagem').val()
  }  
    $.ajax({
              url:'sendEmail.php',
              method:'post',
              dataType:'json',
              data: data, 
              success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                         $('.success').text(data.message);
                    } else {
                        if (data.errors.length > 0) {

                            var errorsList = '<div class="errors-messages">\
                                              <p>Corrija os erros abaixo:</p>\
                                                <ul>';
                            for (var i in data.errors) {
                               errorsList+= "<li>- "+data.errors[i]+"</li>\n"; 
                            }
                            errorsList+= '</ul>\
                                       </div>';
                         $('.errors').html(errorsList);
                        }
                    }

              }
     });
```

E na view, coloque apenas onde irá exibir as mensagens de erro e a mensagem de sucesso:

```
<div class="errors"></div>
<div class="success"></div>
```

Comment: Olá @Iva Ferrer, antes de mais nada muitíssimo obrigado pela grande ajuda, no código postado está acusando erro em duas linhas, a primeira é essa: return json_encode(['success'=>'0','errors'=>$e->getMessage()]);
e a outra é essa:  return json_encode(['success'=>'1','message'=>'Mensagem enviada com sucesso!']);

Comment: Acredito que seja a versão do seu PHP, eu mudei o array, tente novamente.

Comment: Tem uma diferença entre os dois tipos para versões inferiores  `array()` e `[]`.

Comment: agradeço a paciência e a grande ajuda, ficou excelente.